# Verificar palavras que aparecem em foreach

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    <?PHP
$texto1 = file_get_contents('cot.txt');
//adiciona o texto em posições do array
preg_match_all('|texto.\d+(.+?)<\/body>|is', $texto1, $resultado);
$textos = $resultado[1];
    $arrayCot =  explode(" ", file_get_contents('PalavrasCot.txt'));
    $arra = $textos[$n];
            foreach($arrayCot as $valor){
                if (strpos($arra, $valor) !== false) {
                    $contCot++;
                    $ArzCot[$n] = $contCot;
                }
            }
    ?>
```

Nesse código, ele lê um arquivo de texto, separa o conteúdo e verifica se as palavras existem em um arquivo separado (no cód. `$arrayCot`).
Minha dúvida é:
Como mostrar, quantas vezes cada palavra em `$arrayCot` apareceu.
Texto em `PalavrasCot.txt`:

```
parque. parque, parque brincadeiras. brincadeiras, brincadeiras mães mães, mães. filho, filho. filho acidente. acidente, acidente venda venda, venda. família família natureza, natureza. natureza carro. carro, carro crianças, crianças. crianças escola, escola. escola
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos partir de que o texto original esteja em `$texto` e a listagem de palavras em `$palavras`, só para simplificar a leitura.

Um algoritmo relativamente simples é este:

```
$aTexto = explode( ' ', $texto );
$aPalavras = explode( ' ', $palavras );
$contagem = array();

foreach( $aTexto as $pTexto ) {
    if( in_array( $pTexto, $aPalavras ) ) {
        $contagem[$pTexto] = isset( $contagem[$pTexto] ) ? $contagem[$pTexto] + 1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/POtP3y)**.

Para localizar as palavras no *array* `$aPalavras`, usamos o `in_array`:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php

**Considerações**

Foge um pouco da pergunta, mas é importante observar algumas coisas. O código precisaria, para uso em situações reais, de algumas melhorias.

- Não há tratamento de espaços e quebras de linha. Provavelmente antes do `explode` ajudaria se normalizasse espaços duplos, tabulações e quebras de linha para espaços simples.
- sua lista de palavras depende de repetição com vírgulas e pontos, o que gera dois problemas: um deles é que a contagem separa em cada grupo. Provavelmente numa situação real, a lista contaria somente palavras, e o algoritmo tiraria o ponto e a vírgula (e quaisquer caracteres mais que precisar remover) antes de fazer a busca. Bastaria esta mudança:

  ```
  if( in_array( rtrim( $pTexto, '.,;!?' ), $aPalavras ) ) {
  ```

  Assim, você elimina a necessidade de ter as palavras repetidas na listagem.
- maiúsculas e minúsculas não funcionam na sua proposta original. A solução seria, por exemplo, cadastrar todas as palavras em minúscula no dicionário de busca, e usar esta função para normalizar no texto:

  ```
  if( in_array( mb_strtolower( $pTexto ) ), $aPalavras ) ) {
  ```

  Notar que neste caso, o *charset* do PHP precisa estar configurado corretamente para o formato dos arquivos, senão você terá problemas com acentuação.
- finalmente, numa aplicação real você normalmente não carregaria o texto todo na memória como faz hoje. Poderia simplesmente ir lendo o texto em blocos, e à medida que encontrar espaços, já fazer a contagem. Desta forma, não fica com duplicidade de dados na memória (mantendo o *array* e o texto original desnecessariamente até obter um resultado).